# Auth with SSH key with passphrase and auth pass on CentOS 7

Tags: ssh, centos, openssh

I saw it was possible to use a SSH key (with passphrase) and a password for authentication
on: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17931/possible-to-use-both-private-key-and-password-authentication-for-ssh-login
I have a CentOS 7 remote VPS and a Windows local machine.

I made a `public` and `private` key (`SSH-2 RSA, 2048 bits with passphrase`) with PuTTYgen on my Windows machine.

On CentOS I added the pasteable public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, when I was a root user.
I also changed the permissions of the folder, with:
`sudo chmod g-w ~/ && sudo chmod 755 ~/.ssh && sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Then I changed `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to:

```
Protocol 2

PermitRootLogin yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes

AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
AuthenticationMethods "publickey,password"
```

And I restarted the SSH server with `sudo systemctl restart sshd.service`.
I didn't close Putty on this Windows local machine.

I wanted to check on a other Windows machine if it worked.
I added the private ppk file to Pageant, and also pointed it to that file in Putty.
But then when I try to open the connection Putty gives this error message:

```
"disconnected no supported authentication methods available server sent publickey".
```

What can be the problem, how can I auth with a SSH key (with passphrase) and a root password?

Comment: Please check the syslog/systemd files. This *usually* has to do with permissions.

Comment: In /var/log/secure I also see `key_read: key_from_blob \n failed`, I used the pasteable public key but I placed a enter after ssh-rsa and after the hash. That's not allowed?

Comment: The entire string must me on one line, yes

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try `chmod 700` on the `.ssh/` directory as the SSH config should *only* be accessible by the user itself. Also, is the user the owner of the `.ssh/` directory and files? (`chown -R <user>: .ssh/`).

Kudo's for leaving the current session open, people often forget this and lock themselves out.